# WPF: Хранение файла с данными в папке установленного приложения

Tags: c#, wpf

На данный момент я понятия не имею, как осуществляется финальная сборка WPF-приложения для его распространения (что-то читал, но пока чёткой картины в голове пока не сложилось). Из того, что знаю: один из вариантов - возможность собрать приложение в установочный файл.

Но сейчас меня интересует вот что. Допустим, у меня в приложении есть файл с данными (допустим `.json`, а бывает что и вообще `.txt` парсить требуют) и он хранится внутри проекта. Но что будет с этим файлом при финальной сборке приложения? Конкретно я хочу, чтобы этот файл хранился в папке с установленным приложением, а не в "Моих документах" и не в "AppData".

Comment: А вы файл перезаписывать собираетесь или только читать? Помните, что в папке, куда будет установлено приложение у пользователь вполне может не быть прав на запись

Comment: @Андрей, Буду перезаписывать. А что если в "AppData" хранить?

Comment: В AppData можно, она лежит в папке пользователя, поэтому у него есть все права на нее

Comment: @Андрей, Ясно. Спасибо за информацию! Теперь, если меня спросят, "Почему я сделал такой выбор?", то смогу всё объяснить.

Comment: С другой стороны, если ваше приложение переносное, то будет плохо, если файлы с данными будут храниться отдельно - пользователи будут их терять при переносе приложения, например, на флешке

Comment: @Андрей, Нет, не переносное. Вообще, переносные приложения - явление редкое :) Особенно сейчас, когда широко применяются технологии облачного хранения данных.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужен Setup Project.

Если его нет, качать отсюда - https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudio2015InstallerProjects

Этот проект позволит создавать .msi сборку которая запуститься как стандартный установщик Windows. Уже там вы сможете указывать какие файлы должны находится в папке с установленной программой, добавить ярлык на рабочий стол, установить свои шрифты в систему и многое другое.

Для этого создаем проект:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

далее - правой кнопкой по решению : добавить -> создать проект или существующий проект (открываете WPF проект который должен быть установлен).

Далее правой кнопкой по Deployment Setup Properties : добавить -> выходной элемент проекта -> выбираете проект и основные выходные файлы проекта.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь обратите внимание на папки `User's Programs Menu`, `Application Folder`, `User's Desktop` . Вам нужна `Application Folder` - заходите в нее и видите что там уже есть элемент с названием вроде `Основные выходные файлы проекта ...`.
Правой кнопкой по пустому месту - > Добавить -> Файл. Далее откроется обозреватель в котором вы можете выбрать файл, который при установке так же будет находится в папке с распакованным приложением наряду с .exe и .dll. Затем остается только собрать установщик : правой кнопкой по `Deployment Setup Properties` -> `Пересобрать`. Если все правильно то на выходе вы получите .msi установщик после работы которого все нужные файлы будут распакованы в папку с exe файлом.

Comment: Благодарю Вас за подробный ответ! Благодаря Вам, я уже гораздо лучше себе представляю процесс финальной сборки и последующей установки приложения.Подскажите пожалуйста насчет существующего проекта: то, что Вы говорили, что "WPF проект который должен быть установлен" означает, что надо осуществить сборку WPF-приложения каким-то другими образом, не просто `Build Solution (F7)`?

Comment: @GurebuBokofu В проект установщика нужно добавить только .sln файл вашего решения. осуществлять сборку не нужно тк Setup Project соберет проект самостоятельно.

Answer (score 2):

Файлы в каталоге программы не принадлежат конкретному юзеру, они общие для всех юзеров на данной машине (Windows, начиная с NT, уже давно не однопользовательская система.)

Поэтому каталог `Program Files`, в котором хранятся приложения, недоступен юзерам для записи (иначе изменения одного юзера будут мешать изменениям другого юзера). Для файлов, которое будут меняться, правильное место расположения — подкаталог вашего приложения в каталоге `%APPDATA%`.

Имеет смысл при первом старте программы данным пользователем создавать «чистый» файл в `%APPDATA%\Название вашего приложения\`, и хранить изменения в нём. Оригинал «чистого» файла можно либо держать в каталоге инсталляции (для этого подойдёт setup-проект), либо включить его в главную программу как ресурс.